# A home button in iOS 5, xcode 4.2, Story board

Tags: xcode, ios5, navigation, storyboard

iOS 5.0, xCode 4.2

I am doing a multistep questionnaire.

There are about 10 questions on each branch, and there are sub branches.
But the logic is fairly linear. Mostly Yes/no answers, but some multi choice options.
The questionnaire will come to a conclusion page.

On this conclusion page, I would like to have a button that says HOME 
which takes the user to a specific start page so they can start again.

The problem is that I want the navigation controller stack to be cleared so the back buttons will not loop through the past selections.

Put another way, I want to clear out all of the view controllers on the navigation stack.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` on UINavigationController will clear out the stack and return you to the root controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the viewControllers property of UINavigationController. This can even be done animated.